# Threading with recursive call in different class

Tags: java, multithreading

Working on a project with multithreading for the first time. Its quite long, so ill spare you the code. I have a bunch of different classes. The main two for this issue is a threader class, and a class called “neighbour”. In the neighbour class I have a recursive method called walk. Simplified, it looks a bit like this:

```
class Neighbour {
    void Walk() {
         if(upNeighbour.alive()) {
            upNeighbour.Walk();
         }
         if (downNeighbour.alive()) {
             Thread n = new Thread();
             n.start();
         }
```

And now I want this recursive call going in a thread.
The `run()` in my thread class, calls for the first `Walk()`
And my code works so that if at least one of the neighbours can walk, the old thread will walk, and walk last ofc, for effective threading.

But my question is if this recursive call in the walk method (which is not in the same class as the thread class, and is not called on by the thread class except for the very first time) will all happen in the thread? Or do I need to put the entire recursive walk method in the `run()`?

Comment: "walk last ofc", what does that mean? Check your spelling before posting! And please try and keep to Java coding conventions with regard to white-space and lowercase method names. I've never seen anybody put a space before `;` yet, but none before a `{`. Creation of your own style is OK, but that's too far off the path..

Comment: Walk last, as in the old thread must walk last, because if i prioritize the old thread, there will be no multithreading. But yea, bad english.
Should probably have said that this is totally pseudocode, I do not have a class Neighbour or a method walk, just an easy example as the program is a bit too complicated to post out of context or in its entirety.
As for the coding conventions, had no idea, thank you. No professor has ever corrected me on that, Ive just allways put a space before ;, and none before {

Comment: That's strange. At university the first code was held against strict standards. Note that professors are not always the best programmers (some are actually quite bad at it, in my experience). I'd recommend posting *working* Java source code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com if you're interested in a thorough breakdown! Maybe start by reading a couple of reviews there that focus on coding standards.

Comment: I'm not fully getting your question I think. The problem is that the problem is condensed too much. Note that any method called from the `run()` method is being run in the same thread context. Is that what you're asking?